# C# If checkbox is checked within panel then continue

Tags: c#, checkbox, foreach, panel, checked

I am trying to find the easiest way to populate an access database if a checkbox within my panel is checked. If no checkboxes are checked then dont do anything. Below is what i have, however when i select more than 1 checkbox i get an error:

> Changes would create duplicate values to the index

```
foreach (Control c in panel4.Controls.Cast<Control>())
{
    if (c is CheckBox)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)c).Checked)
        {
            string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\\test\\Comm.accdb";

            string cmdstr = "Insert into test(inc1,inc2,inc3,inc3,inc4,inc5)Values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f)";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
            con.Open();

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", label6.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", textBox1.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", comboBox3.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", checkBox17.CheckState);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", checkBox16.CheckState);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", checkBox18.CheckState);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats not verbatim the error is it.  Its probably `The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key or relationship`

Comment: What are the indexes and primary key that you have on table `test`?

Comment: Each Parameter in my code is one field withing my database. inc1 is my primary key. What my foreach code is doing is creating a new entry(row) into my for each checkbox checked. Instead of just putting the data into one row.

Comment: So, why would you have a user entered primary key?  Sent your primary key to a integer auto increment field, and let the label6.Text be a varchar column.

Comment: So, to clarify, your error is because you are trying to insert the value of `label6.Text` multiple times.  Once for each control on your form into your primary key.  As primary keys must be unique, this throws an error.

Comment: label6.text generates a primary key based on what the user enters in a form. In this case i am just trying to check for any checkboxes that are checked. If any are checked within my panel then continue with submitting my data.

Comment: So, if two boxes are checked, the sql is executed twice, no second primary key is created.  I should emphasis that generating a primary key outside your database, is very bad practice, let the database do that.

Comment: Correct, i only want the sql to execute once and only generate primary key once. Thanks for feedback! After i figure out how to do it this way ill revisit and update the database key.

Comment: Loop the controls, figure out which are checked, set variables accordingly, then after the loop call a method that has your sql.